# Iteración Deque vs Stream vs List estándar

Tags: java, bucles, arraylist, java-8, complejidad

Repasando código legacy me he encontrado con un parche bastante interesante que ha generado algo de debate dentro de mi empresa:

La cuestión es tan sencilla como recorrer una lista, lo que normalmente hacemos de 2 formas distintas:

Opción 1 (estándar)

```
            for (int i = 0; i < listaTarifas.size(); i++) { 
                //DO THINGS
            }
```

Opción 2 (Programación funcional)

```
listaTarifas.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> String.valueOf(s.get("credto")),       
                s -> s.get("xliter")));
```

Sin embargo, corrigiendo un bug he localizado esta nueva opción con Deque:

Opción 3 (Localizada en legacy) a diferencia de las dos primeras no estamos trabajando con List, sino con Deque

```
while (listaTarifas.size() != 0) {                      
    j++;
    listaTarifas.getFirst() //DO SOMETHING
    listaTarifas.removeFirst();                       
}
```

A priori entiendo que el getFirst y el removeFirst tienen una complejidad linear por lo que en Deque debería de ser extremadamente eficiente, pero.

¿Es mas rápido que la opción 1?
¿Es más rápido que la opción 2?

Asumo que debería ser mas rápido que la opción 1 pero menos que la 2 pero no estoy del todo seguro (aun no estoy totalmente familiarizado con Deque)

PD: solo me interesa la velocidad de recorrido no de inserción.

Comment: La respuesta depende un poco de qué tipo de lista estás usando, de todas maneras la programación funcional no se usa por "ser más rápida", yo no asumiría que la opción 2 es más rápida que la 1, de hecho, me parece justo todo lo contrario. Un bucle for normalito para acceder a los elementos de una lista es bastante rápido, en cambio crear un mapa para recorrer la lista me parece una barbaridad (a no ser que la creación del mapa sea el objetivo de recorrer la lista, tus ejemplos 1 y 2 son códigos completamente diferentes que hacen cosas diferentes y no lo que indicas en el caso del 2!).

Comment: De todas maneras, si lo único que te interesa es recorrer una lista, usar una cola no es lo más rápido puesto que cada vez que eliminas el primero necesitas reasignarlo, hacer la asignación es un paso innecesario si tan solo quieres recorrer la lista sin modificar nada. Las colas están bien para muchas cosas, pero no la usaría para recorrer una lista linealmente por todo el overhead que conlleva y que no es necesario. Harás trabajar al GC más de la cuenta de manera innecesaria, cosa que también hay que tener en cuenta a la hora de medir el impacto en el sistema.

Comment: Un for normal debería ser lo mas rápido, es lo mas directo y no implica la sobrecarga o la creación adicional de objetos. Si solo te preocupa la velocidad de recorrido no tiene sentido usar colas porque no son para eso, los streams servirían si necesitaras realizar operaciones de mapeo, filtrado o reducción sobre los elementos porque proporcionan una sintaxis mas expresiva pero en este caso no es lo mejor.

Comment: Tenéis razón respecto al caso II) si bien lo he puesto como ejemplo, no es el mejor ejemplo de lo que trataba de ejemplificar. Respecto al bucle for normal (opción 1) en lugar de la opción 3 creo que os entiendo, el tema de la reasignación todo el tiempo se come la posible mejora que pueda ganar realizando estas operaciones en la opción 3. Es diferente operar puntualmente que en bucle.